# Faster way to find the correct order of chunks to get a known SHA1 hash?

Tags: hash

Say a known SHA1 hash was calculated by concatenating several chunks of data and that the order in which the chunks were concatenated is unknown. The straight forward way to find the order of the chunks that gives the known hash would be to calculate an SHA1 hash for each possible ordering until the known hash is found.

Is it possible to speed this up by calculating an SHA1 hash separately for each chunk and then find the order of the chunks by only manipulating the hashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, No.

If you are using SHA-1, due to [Avalanche Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect) ,any tiny change in the plaintext (in your case, your chunks) would alter its corresponding SHA-1 significantly.

Say if you have 4 chunks : **A B C** and **D**,
the SHA1 hash of **A+B+C+D (concated)** is **supposed** to be uncorrelated with the SHA1 hash for **A, B, C and D** computed as separately.

Since they are unrelated, you cannot draw any relationship between the **concated chunk (A+B+C+D, B+C+A+D etc)** and each **individual chunk (A,B,C or D)**.

If you could identify any relationship in-between, the SHA1 hashing algorithm would be in trouble.

Answer (score 3):

**Practical answer:** no. If the hash function you use is any good, then it is supposed to look like a [Random Oracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle), the output of which on an exact given input being totally unknown until that input is tried. So you cannot infer anything from the hashes you compute until you hit the exact input ordering that you are looking for. (Strictly speaking, there *could* exist a hash function which has the usual properties of a hash function, namely collision and preimage resistances, without being a random oracle, but departing from the RO model is still considered as a hash function weakness.)(Still strictly speaking, it is slightly improper to talk about a random oracle for a single, unkeyed function.)

**Theoretical answer:** it depends. Assuming, for simplicity, that you have *N* chunks of 512 bits, then you can arrange for the cost not to exceed *N*2<sup>160</sup>* elementary evaluations of SHA-1, which is lower than *N!* when *N >= 42*. The idea is that the running state of SHA-1, between two successive blocks, is limited to 160 bits. Of course, that cost is ridiculously infeasible anyway. More generally, your problem is about finding a preimage to SHA-1 with inputs in a custom set *S* (the *N!* sequences of your *N* chunks) so the cost has a lower bound of the size of *S* and the preimage resistance of SHA-1, whichever is lower. The size of *S* is *N!*, which grows very fast when *N* is increased. SHA-1 has no known weakness with regards to preimages, so its resistance is still assumed to be about *2<sup>160</sup>* (since it has a 160-bit output).

**Edit:** this kind of question would be appropriate on the [proposed "cryptography" stack exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15811/cryptography?referrer=95QTE2xbAsOQqTER2XreYQ2), when (if) it is instantiated. Please commit to help create it !

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your hashing library, something like this may work: Say you have blocks A, B, C, and D. You can process the hash for block A, and then clone that state and calculate A+B, A+C, and A+D without having to recalculate A each time. And then you can clone each of those to calculate A+B+C and A+B+D from A+B, A+C+B and A+C+D from A+C, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  Calculating the complete SHA1 hash requires that the chunks be put in in order.  The calculation of the next hash chunk requires the output of the current one.  If that wasn't true then it would be much easier to manipulate documents so that you could reorder the chunks at will, which would greatly decrease the usefulness of the algorithm.